# asp.net handle page early?

Tags: asp.net

In my **Application_BeginRequest** I have a list of things I check for rewriting purposes. At the very end I rewrite all paths to default.aspx which then simply has the following

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableSessionState="False"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyWebsite"%>
<% PageRequest.WritePage();%>
```

There probably no (aka nearly nonexistent) overhead but I'll ask anyways. Instead of rewriting, can I just call **WritePage** instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what `PageRequest.WritePage` does and whether you care about the page lifecycle. `BeginRequest` is just the first event in the page lifecycle. If you are rendering the entire page in this method, and have no controls then just call `Response.End` afterwards.

Keeping the code in the `default.aspx` has the advantage that you can still use output caching. If you have a lot of logic in `WirtePage` and this content is cachable, then this will be a significant performance gain.

Comment: hmm interesting. Well, can caching work for dynamic pages? all my static content (img, js, etc) set the cache headers (browsers side cache). What does the cache do? In many of my sites users are not logged in but would cache help there? i may not need it since my sql and page code seem to be fast (.01-0.02 of a sec)

Comment: `OutputCache` can be used to cache content both server-side and/or client-side. It works for dynamic pages, you just need to tell it what parameters to base the cache on, using `VaryByHeader`, `VaryByParam` etc. You can implement your own cache rules with `VaryByCustom`. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx). It makes a difference to scalability of your site if you need to handle large volumes of traffic.